# Who or what attains moksha?

Tags: vedanta, upanishads, atma, moksha

When we talk about liberation among the living i.e the jeevanmukts, is it their aatman which has achieved realization? If not the aatman, that what/who? For those who have done good karma in this birth and are guaranteed escape from the cycle of rebirth, what achieves moksha after loss of body/mind on death?

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28712/is-liberation-for-mind-or-atman

Comment: Are you asking the question as per Vedanta and Upanishads only ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is liberation for mind or Atman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28712/is-liberation-for-mind-or-atman)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Hinduism SE! Unfortunately this question is a duplicate. In future, please try the search bar to verify whether or not your question has been answered. It can be a bit difficult to find due to the nature of this stack exchange, so please don't be discouraged when a question is closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The Jivatma attains realization that it is part of Paramaatma. Technically,  recognizing "*Pratyabhijna*" of one's true nature which is "*akrtrima-aham-vimarsa*" - the original, innate, pure I- consciousness.

Relevant scripture is "*Siva sutras*" Tantra I. Pg 192. and its commentary by Abhinav Gupta.

*"Moksho he nama Nowanyahe swaroopaprathan he tatha"*

Meaning,
Moksha or liberation is nothing else but awareness of one's true nature.

The highest attainment is that of Siva-consciousness in which the entire universe appears as I or Siva and this comes by Saktipata - The descent of Divine *Sakti* or her grace *Anugraha*.

In order to attain Her grace there are four *upayas* (spiritual discipline) mentioned *Anupaya*, *Sambhavopaya*, *Saktopaya* and *Anavopaya*.

All Part of Kashmiri Shaivism and its excellent books.

Except *Anupaya*, the rest of the methods are spiritual discipline / Yoga one must have for attaining Moksha. The Siva Sutras cover the Yoga paths.

*Anupaya* is really interesting. It says that no description of it can be given. Sometimes, a guru tells a word and you get Self realization! It is sort of a "Reserved" part for knowledgable Gurus to induce Self-realization to an aspirant and is *Gupt* or secret.

Since, it is a secret you cannot find written descriptions of that.

To answer your second question, Good karmas are insufficient without Her Grace which in-turn means you should come under the category of any of the above *Upayas*.

The Yoga/Vedic path covers *vidya* ( Knowledge acquisition about Moksha and spiritual discipline) and *avidya* ( doing *Nityakarma*s, *Yagna*, *Homa*s etc.) after doing all that you will be evaluated for Her grace to attain Moksha after you leave the body.

That covers the scripture descriptions.

But honestly and practically, How many people are thinking about re-birth and Moksha as they go about their daily activities except Monks who are dedicated? Let's pause and answer these questions

1) Why do you want Moksha?

If you say to chant the name of Lord for eternity then there are already a lot of souls who have attained Moksha doing exactly that. Of what use is your Moksha?

2) Shouldn't Monk's sacrifice and dedication warrant a Moksha?

Yes it should. However, without knowing the Real world which is run by Paramatma, How helpful will you be in running the World? Without full experience of the real world your knowledge level is insufficient to help Paramatma. That is the reason, Sanatana Dharma insisted on going through the stages of Life, starting with *Brahmacharin, Grahastrama, Vanastashrama* and on to become a real Saint and upon departure helps Paramatma in some way. Don't forget that the "Mayic" world that you see should continue to exist post your departure and certainly The Creator neither you would prefer to go back to "Darkness covered by Darkness" ( as per *Nasadaya Sukta*). For one thing that is really boring!

My two cents!

Answer (score 0):

Moksha doesnot means disappearance of physical body from the physical world, that happens for the bound soul that is starting everything from zero in every birth with new set of parents, environment and everything. For Moksha/enlightenment is of the mind but neither of body nor Atman. What is Maya? Maya means ignorance, forgetfulness and inflated ego. **Moksha means living in one cosmic consciousness** [Parbrahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Para_Brahman) [Satchidananda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satcitananda) Atman(one who has no Tamas and never sleeps/forgets) without hating and fighting others in the name of personal temporary ego and satisfaction for sensual pleasures. God/consciousness can be approached through several paths like Bhakti, Gyan and Karma Yoga etc.,. Thats what enlightened Purusha Krishna told to Arjuna.

[Bhagwat Geeta Chapter 4](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/4)

> Bhagavad Gita 4.4 Arjun said: You were born much after Vivasvan. How
> am I to understand that in the beginning you instructed this science
> to him?
>
> Bhagavad Gita 4.5 The Supreme Lord said: **Both you and I have had many
> births, O Arjun. You have forgotten them, while I remember them all, O
> Parantapa.**

Highest Moksha(i.e. state of [Jivanmukta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jivanmukta)) or [Kaivalya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaivalya) or oneness with Nirguna Brahman Purusha as mentioned in Vedas is very rare to attain among humans, one in million.

> Bhagavad Gita 7.3 Amongst thousands of persons, hardly one strives for
> perfection; and amongst those who have achieved perfection, hardly one
> knows me in truth.

Thats why Krishna told Arjuna to do Bhakti of Saguna Brahman first to purify mind
and Rama told the same thing to Hanuman.
[Muktika Upanishad](http://www.vedarahasya.net/muktika.htm)

> I-i-15-17. Hanuman: Rama, sages speak differently: some say there is
> only one kind of liberation. Others say it can be got by worshipping
> your name and by the Taraka mantra at Kashi. Others speak of
> Sankhya-Yoga and Bhakti-Yoga, the enquiry into Vedanta-Vakyas etc.
>
> I-i-18-23. **Rama: Liberation is of four kinds: Salokya, Sampeepya, Sarupya,
> Sayujya etc. But the only real type is Kaivalya.** Anybody even though
> leading a wicked life, attains Salokya, not other worlds, by
> worshipping my name. Dying in the sacred Brahmanala in Kashi, he will
> get the Taraka-mantra and also liberation, without rebirth. On dying
> anywhere (else) in Kashi, Maheshvara will utter the Taraka-mantra in
> his right ear. He gets Sarupya with me as his sins are washed away.
>
> The same is called Salokya and Sarupya. Persevering in good conduct,
> with mind fixed upon me, loving me as the Self of all, the twice-born
> gets nearer to me – This is called the three forms of liberation.
> Salokya, Sarupya and Samipya
>
> I-i-26-29. But by what means is the Kaivalya kind of Moksha got ? The
> Mandukya is enough; if knowledge is not got from it, then study the
> Ten Upanishads. Getting knowledge very soon, you will reach my abode.
> If certainty is not got even then, study the 32 Upanishads and stop.
> If desiring Moksha without the body, read the 108 Upanishads.
>
> I-i-40-43. These destroy three kinds of Bhavana (regarding) body,
> senses and mind respectively as identified with Atman. **The best of
> Brahmanas will become Jivanmuktas if they study upto the destruction
> of Prarabdha, these 108 Upanishads from a Guru along with the
> Shanti-pada. Then, in course of time they will get Vedeha-mukti,
> surely.**

[Ramkrishna Paramhans](https://selfdefinition.org/celibacy/gopal-krishna-collection/quotes-by-ramakrishna-paramahamsa-part-2.htm)

> Bound souls, worldly people, are like silkworms. They could come out
> of their cocoons if they wished, but they have built their own homes
> and maya does not allow them to escape. And it all ends with death.
> Liberated souls are not under the control of 'lust and greed'. Some
> clever silkworms cut their cocoons and come out.But they are very few.
> **Because of maya (attachment), one remains forgetful. Few are not
> deluded by the magic of maya**, are not subject to the control of 'lust
> and greed.' When the pot containing ashes from the maternity room
> falls on one's feet, the 'damn, damn' word of the magician can do no
> harm. One can see exactly what the magician is doing.
>
> If you first fortify yourself with the true knowledge of the Universal
> Self, and then live in the midst of wealth and worldliness, surely
> they will in no way affect you.

But seek first his kingdom and his righteousness, and all these material things will be given to you as well.Whoever has the true knowledge will be given more, and they will have an abundance. Whoever does not have the truth, even what they have will be taken from them by death and forgetfulness