# How advait is mayavad as per Vaishnav ideology?

Tags: advaita, gaudiya-vaishnavism

I know the argument is that it leads to impersonal idea of God but where does Maya comes into the play as per their theology ?

https://youtu.be/hN9KpDg9X0g

Comment: Advaitins consider God's form(s) and all attributes are due to Maya. Gaudiya Vaishnavas (and most other theists) consider God's attributes as real.

Comment: As per Advait, world is not real(absolutely). That which makes the world look real to us inspite of it being unreal is owing to maya (energy of ishwar) . Those who subscribe to this world view are called mayavadins. 13th Shankaracharya of Shringeri Shri Vidyaranya Swami in his panchadashi has used world "mayavadi" for themselves. He says "appearance of world even without any reality of it is mayavad and we are mayavadi, this mayavad is our ornamanent".

Comment: Advaita is for Gyanis who seek the one formless master transcendent state of masculine Purusha while Vaishnavism and other forms of Bhakti are for Bhakts who dont mind the finite divisions of world and body given by feminine Prakriti. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36974/16530

Comment: Thank you for your responses everyone.