# Does dharma and adharma applicable to a Jivan Muktha?`

Tags: scripture, dharma, mukti

It is well known that a person who is not a Jivan Muktha is bounded by Dharma and Adharma. That is, one needs to do dharma only as per scriptures.

What about a person who achieved a Jivan Muktha state. Is Dharma and Adharma are still applicable to that person?

Comment: I think the answer to the above question is present here- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36919/can-jivan-mukta-continue-his-her-own-profession/36974#36974

Comment: Does not apply as per both Kularnava as well as Yogavashishta. But only when the person is a true Jivanmukta.

Comment: @Rickross Haha... True Jivan Mukta

Comment: @Rickross And it seems that this question is an extension to one of my previous questions in the comment by  SwiftPishkar

Comment: Yes, because a true Jivanmukta is rare. We might not know any such person at all. @hanugm For such persons Dharma-Adharma rules don't apply, whatever they order becomes scriptures, whatever they utter becomes mantra.

Comment: Yes the same verses can be used here as well. @hanugm

Comment: @Rickross Yeah...